# Calculating grid to ground correction angle manually

Tags: arcinfo-workstation, aml

I've been running into problems at work with calculating a correction angle manually. The coworker that has been training me in ArcInfo 8 showed me a formula that I have yet to get to get to work - subtracting the bearing the line was originally drawn as from the one on the plat but carrying over a minute(60) or second(60) instead of one. I did ask for clarification but in his own words, he has forgotten more than I'll ever know and just knows that it works for him. As a stop-gap, I've been incrementing through until I get the "right" correction angle. Is there any kind of reference for this type of calculation? This wasn't covered in the GIS certification program I had, and googling hasn't returned much at all.

---

I was taught by my coworker that when the bearing in our GIS (the "Grid" bearing in the screen shot) doesn't match whats on the plat I'm drawing that I need to use the "constant" (the "const" command used in the screen shot) function in ArcInfo to adjust the "Ground" bearing that you see in the screen shot using a correction angle. Right now, I am guessing as to the values to use for this correction angle. I'll grab a definition for "inv line sel" and "const" from the help file when I get to work, I can't recall exactly what it is right now.

I don't have any formal education in COGOing legal descriptions. I'm running off of what I've been taught by my coworker and I'm worried he will retire before I figure this out.

[image: This is what I've been doing, it works but is horribly inefficient.]

Comment: wow arcinfo workstation (1990's) - is this an aml? what is the algorithm used? your screenshot is just the results.

Comment: you definitely need to give us more information about what you're trying to do, and the formula you're using

Comment: This sounds ripe for a re-write from AML to ArcPy.

Comment: @PolyGeo if it's still working aside from one minor problem, why change everything? I'm happy to refresh my memory on AML if necessary ;)

Comment: @StephenLead Phew!  I thought I might turn around and find I was the only one with my hand still up for AML.

Comment: I reckon Michael Miles-Stimpson might give it us a run for our money

Comment: @PolyGeo I'm familiar with ArcPy, is there a reference anywhere for that?

Comment: @StephenLead The formula I gave in the paragraph is literally what I was told, but I'll go look at my notes more closely when I get back to the office.

Comment: @annag I could probably read the AML to write the ArcPy but I'm not a surveyor or American so plats mean nothing to me.

Comment: @PolyGeo I'll see what I can turn up when I get to the office, thank you

Comment: Please be aware that any help I provide would only be as a code snippet per question.

Comment: @PolyGeo, sorry if I mislead ya'll - this isn't an AML at all but ARCEDIT commands.

from the help file:
CONSTANTS - 
sets the ground-to-grid correction angle and scale factor.

CONSTANTS <correction_angle> {scale_factor}

Arguments

<correction_angle> - specifies the ground-to-grid correction angle.  This may be either a negative or positive number; for example, N5E or -2.5.  The default correction angle when ARCEDIT begins execution is 0.  This required parameter can be skipped by entering a #, which allows you to enter an optional {scale_factor} without changing the <correction_angle>.

Comment: (continued)
{scale_factor} - specifies the ground-to-grid scale factor.  The default scale factor when ARCEDIT begins execution is 1.

Comment: inv line sel from the screen shot is:

INVERSE

displays the geometry and attributes associated with a line, curve, spiral, or two points.  Additionally, the angle defined by three points or the coordinates of a point can be displayed.

INVERSE <LINE | CURVE | SPIRAL> {SELECT}

INVERSE <POINT> {* | xy | P<n>}

INVERSE <DISTANCE> {* | xy | P<n>} {* | xy | P<n>}

INVERSE <ANGLE> {* | xy | P<n>} {* | xy | P<n>} {* | xy | P<n>}

Comment: (continued)

Arguments

<LINE | CURVE | SPIRAL> - specifies whether the inverse direction and distance of a line, circular curve, or spiral will be displayed.

LINE - the inverse data about a line will be displayed.

{SELECT} - specifies that the inverse direction and distance will be displayed for the currently selected line, circular curve, or spiral.  If this option is not specified, you will be prompted to interactively select the desired line, curve, or spiral to be inversed.

Comment: [this is the "formula"](http://imgur.com/vRWItxf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula is just how to find the difference between two degree-minute-second values. 1 deg = 60 min, 1 min = 60 sec, so if you need to borrow because the first sec value is less then the second value, you borrow 1 minute or 60 seconds. Same thing if you have to borrow 1 degree because the first minutes value is less than the second one.

You can also do this using the windows calculator. Enter the first value as:

```
Enter 15.4715 (DD.MMSS)
press Inv key
press Deg key (result 15.7875 in decimal degrees)
press subtract
Enter second value as 13.5051
press Inv key
press Deg key (result is 13.8475)
press = key (1.94)
press dms key (1.5624 aka 1 deg 56 min 24 sec)
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I thought it was something like that, but my lack of education in this specific arena is holding me back. I'm still trying to find a textbook or any other kind of reference material for this.

Comment: Maybe Basic GIS Coordinates by Jan Van SIckle or an elementary Surveying book like Ghilani/Wolf, Moffitt/Bouchard or an edition of Davis/Foote/Anderson/Mikhail (my copy is 20+ years old)